Как правильно указать dns-сервера для PPPOE подключений на Ubuntu-server-18?
/etc/ppp/peers/dls-provider
Сейчас такой конфиг
noipdefault
usepeerdns
defaultroute
hide-password
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3
# Override any connect script that may have been set in /etc/ppp/options.
connect /bin/true
noauth
persist
mtu 1492
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
plugin rp-pppoe.so
nic-enp42s0
user "user1"

Можно ли прям здесь указать нужный DNS?
К компу несколько провайдеров подключены, чтобы каждый PPPOE использовал свои DNS сервера.
